# ColdFusion 10 Mandatory Update install fails on VM

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I need to run the mandatory update for ColdFusion 10 so I can apply the later updates to the server.  I downloaded the file and tried the instructions listed here: [Mandatory Update Instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Admin/WSe61e35da8d318518-33adffe0134c60cd31c-7ffe.html).

I have a singular instance, so this should be fairly straightforward.  I download the file, place it in the "hf-updates" folder, and then do `java -jar cf10_man_updt.jar` and I get the following notice:

> Graphical installers are not supported by the VM.  The console mode
>   will be used instead...

The installer proceeds to hang and fails to complete. I then go to option #2: Silent mode. I create my properties file and then do `java -jar cf10_mdt_updt.jar -i silent -f install.cfg.txt`.  I get the following message:

> Installer User Interface Mode Not Supported
>
> Unable to load and to prepare the installer in console or silent mode.

This one has the courtesy to actually terminate so I don't have to close the command prompt window to retry, but I'm still nowhere.  Any ideas on what I can do?

Comment: Whats your OS? Your JDK/JRE is probably incomplete/incompatible. Instead of running the global `java` command, use the one in `/ColdFusion/jre/bin/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex provided the correct answer. I had been using the JRE in my program files folder (explicitly, actually. There was no javapath to speak of in the environment variables. I shorthanded the command for the sake of brevity). I changed the command to `"C:\Coldfusion10\cfusion\jre\bin\java" -jar cf10_mdt_updt.jar` and the install ran successfully.

Comment: Sadly, that is a common gotcha. I really wish the docs would include a default path, instead of just saying *"...run command `java`..."*! BTW, If you are new to S.O., it works a little differently than a forum. If someone else provides the "answer" to your question, it is a nice gesture to ask them to promote their comment to an "answer" and have the chance to gain a few votes. Just a little way of saying thanks for helping out :) If you feel more details would helpful to the next guy, it is fine to post your own, separate answer as well.

Comment: Duly noted.  Thanks.